# Prove: $(a+b) \sqrt {ab}+(a+c) \sqrt {ac}+(b+c)\sqrt {bc}≥ \frac {(a+b+c)^2}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-verification, proof-writing, contest-math

[image]

**EDİTED:**

I tried to solve the last question.I can not get the state of equality and I can not find my mistake. Can you show me my mistake(s)?

> 4.
>   Let, $a,b,c$ be the lengths of sides of a triangle. Prove the inequality:
>
> $$(a+b) \sqrt {ab}+(a+c) \sqrt {ac}+(b+c)\sqrt {bc}≥ \frac {(a+b+c)^2}{2}$$

I will use:

$(1)$

> $\begin{cases} a+b≥2\sqrt{ab} &\\ b+c≥2\sqrt{bc}&\\ a+c≥2\sqrt{ac} \end{cases}\Longrightarrow \begin{cases} (a+b)\sqrt{ab}≥2ab &\\ (b+c)\sqrt{bc}≥2bc&\\ (a+c)\sqrt{ac}≥2ac \end{cases} \Longrightarrow (a+b)\sqrt{ab}+(b+c)\sqrt{bc}+(a+c)\sqrt{ac}≥2(ab+bc+ac)$

$(2)$

> $\begin{cases} b(a+c)>b^2 &\\ c(a+b)>c^2&\\ a(b+c)>a^2 \end{cases}\Longrightarrow 2(ab+bc+ac)>a^2+b^2+c^2 \Longrightarrow \frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2}<ab+bc+ac$

Applying $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have

> $(a+b) \sqrt {ab}+(a+c) \sqrt {ac}+(b+c)\sqrt {bc}- \frac {(a+b+c)^2}{2}≥2ab+2bc+2ac- \frac {(a+b+c)^2}{2}≥ab+bc+ac-\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{2}>0≠≥0$

Comment: Have you tried using [Ravi substitution](https://brilliant.org/wiki/ravi-substitution/), i.e., $a=p+q$, $b=q+r$ and $c=r+p$ for some positive reals $p,q,r\gt 0$ for a non-degenerate triangle?

Comment: Thank you for comment. I am looking for my mistake.

Comment: Why do you think there’s a mistake? Note $3\geqslant 2$ is a true statement.  BTW if you want to post your attempt, use latex rather than images- can’t make out some of it.

Comment: If put $a=b=c$, equality doesn't hold. $LHD=6a^2$, but $RHD=(\frac92)a^2$.

Comment: @Newstudent. Not sure what having a computer has to do with anything - I have used mobiles and all sorts of devices in between. The question remains -  **Why do you believe there is a mistake?**

Comment: @Macavity because there is not equality.

Comment: @Macavity Would you say more clearly? Is my solution correct?

Comment: @Newstudent - Yes, I see nothing wrong with it.

Comment: The equality is achieved only for degenerate triangles (e.g. a = b, c = 0). for non-degenerate triangle, the inequality is strict and there is nothing wrong in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=y+z$, $b=x+z$ and $c=x+y$.

Hence, $x$, $y$ and $z$ are positives and we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}(2x+y+z)\sqrt{(x+y)(x+z)}\geq2(x+y+z)^2$$ and since by C-S $$\sqrt{(x+y)(x+z)}\geq x+\sqrt{yz},$$ it's enough to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}(2x+y+z)(x+\sqrt{yz})\geq2(x+y+z)^2$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\sqrt{x^3y}+\sqrt{x^3z}-2xy+2x\sqrt{yz}\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\sqrt{xy}(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2+2x\sqrt{yz}\right)\geq0.$$
Done!

The equality does not occur because $\sum\limits_{cyc}x\sqrt{yz}>0.$

Comment: The OP asked to show his/her mistake, that is when the equality will occur. The OP is getting strictly more rather more or equal.

Comment: if you pay attention, I didn't label "alternate solution".